# I have a "Element" brand monitor and the driver show up unknown

Tags: monitor

Have the latest 14.04 Ubuntu with a GeForce 7600GS video card. I have downloaded the latest Nvidia 304.125 from Nvidia 304 open source.

I have a "Element" monitor.

My display shows up as unknown.

Is there a correct driver available for this monitor?

I have an issue when the system first starts where the screen is split in two with 1/3 of the display on the right. I have to  move the mouse all the way to the left and then the active Icons can be clicked on.

Thanks!

I am new to Ubuntu. I have other machines and they work flawlessly. Perhaps the video card I am using causing problems. Frankly I don't know how to get 340 or 346.  I don't see them listed. I see the xorg that doesn't work any different. I also see propitiatory and open and was using the open. In the display I still see mirrored on and two listings, one unknow and one is Element. I even had the system black screen one time and found stuff online to use terminal to clear and reinstall to fix that. When starts the mouse won't work but is movable and visable. I have to go all the way to the left and then it like clicks (flashes) and now the Icons are click-able.

Comment: Try another driver, eg: `nvidia-340` or `nvidia-346`.

Comment: Didn't work. Still starts with split screen and mouse off to the left.